# "Nice shoes ..." What does that phrase actually mean?

Tags: american-english, slang, phrase-meaning

As from the title.

I've been receiving this from a security guard, when attending a developer conference, well, a bit overdressed (wearing a suit where all the other nerds just appeared in t-shirt, jeans and sneakers).

But I've also heard that otherwise (not thrown on me, the above anecdote was my only personal experience).

Well, I somehow felt that it's not a compliment, but a subtle insult / belittlement.

I'm not a native speaker. Can someone explain what's the background of that phrase, or where's the joke in it?

Comment: Uhm, so how *nice* is your shoe? Expensive? Trendy? Shiny? Odd? You've heard this once? Or did the security guard say this many times to you? Urban Dictionary has a NSFW definition for ["nice shoes"](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Nice%20Shoes)

Comment: @NVZ Is it just reducing a person to what they're looking alike, and let them know? Well, that guard certainly didn't look homosexual (I'm male) ;-) ... But who knows? He said that once actually, didn't met him later.

Comment: @NVZ Well, then it's _may be a compliment_, but I'll certainly won't take it. THX for the insight.

Comment: It's not a saying. If your shoes are actually nice, then he might be complimenting you. If they are weird/ugly, then he might be poking fun at you/being a bit mean.

Comment: @NVZ Are you sure the link is relevant? I doubt it.

Comment: @Rathony That's all I could find. I haven't heard the phrase used to mean something else than its literal meaning.

Comment: I think most the time when someone says "nice shoes", they're referring to the tasteless pickup line that ends with something NSFW.

Comment: @Othya Well, my experience and other uses I've heard of, definitely didn't go into that direction.

Comment: The question asks what a particular security guard intends by a particular utterance. There is no possibility that the community can answer this with any authority. Unless the security guard chimes in, and even then the answer will not help anybody but the OP. Voting to close.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  I've worked with an film company in New York named "Nice Shoes" (http://www.niceshoes.com/) and there's no question where the name comes from. It's a NSFW inside joke but so well known that nobody misses the implication.

Comment: @JimMack OK, so it's US specific?

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but it's possible that in some gay communities, "nice shoes" means "I want to pick you up."  If the other person gets the implication, he can respond.  If he doesn't, then he takes it to mean "I like your shoes."

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  No doubt it originated in the US and is well-known here, but I couldn't say where else it may have spread to.

Comment: @MετάEd Well, I mentioned that I also heard that in different context than my personal. Sorry I can't find samples for that, that's probably why I'm actually asking.

Comment: As the hipster Kesey, developing the traditional lineage from Vimalakīrti to Chōmei by way of Heraclitus, put it, "go with the flow". Often a pleasantry is best taken as simply a pleasantry. On the scale of such, "nice shoes" is more common in the Google Books corpus than [others](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nice+shoes%2Cnice+boots%2Cnice+tie%2Cnice+tits&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnice%20shoes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnice%20boots%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnice%20tie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnice%20tits%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is impossible to tell from the minimal description of the circumstances surrounding the guard's comment what his intentions were in saying "Nice shoes." On the one hand, there is at least a possibility that the intention was sincerely to compliment you on your shoes. After all, some consultants recommend it as an ingratiating strategy. From David Topus, [*Talk to Strangers: How Everyday, Random Encounters Can Expand Your Business, Career, Income, and Life*](https://books.google.com/books?id=4aBCioax4UEC&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=%22nice+shoes%22+%22nice+tie%22&source=bl&ots=5lEl8XZp1l&sig=yH_TUisS2LIOoqZEtV7WJ5QVKss&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3v_CFjtXMAhVM_WMKHWgRCM4Q6AEIRjAL#v=onepage&q=%22nice%20shoes%22%20%22nice%20tie%22&f=false) (2012):

> Show sensitivity to and awareness of the other person as much as possible. Any positive comment you can make about the other person allows you to accomplish this. You can never go wrong with a compliment: nice suit, **nice shoes**, nice tie, nice purse, nice ring, nice briefcase, and so on. These will get you going in a great conversation direction.

On the other hand, the guard probably wasn't trying to butter you up in order to expand his business, career, income, and life—and you note that you were dressed rather more formally than other attendees at the conference—so it's possible that he was calling out a difference that you were already feeling a bit awkward or self-conscious about, as a form of teasing.

Disapproving references (couched as compliments) to unconventional dress have a long history in business and social settings. I remember reading an article years ago about the extreme rigidity of the unspoken dress code at a well-established San Francisco law firm. The author recounted how he had once arrived at work wearing a yellow, long-sleeve button-down shirt, instead of the standard white, long-sleeve button-down shirt that the unspoken code insisted upon—and one of the partners at the firm, who rarely had anything to say to him, said in passing, "Nice shirt." The author says that he immediately recognized the comment as a rebuke: to have one's clothing choices mentioned at all at the firm was a form of indirect criticism.

Something similar happens in Virginia Woolf's short story, "[The New Dress](https://books.google.com/books?id=o1AbAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT2078&dq=%22Mabel%27s+got+a+new+dress%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVutXajdXMAhVR52MKHUs4DrwQ6AEIPDAF#v=onepage&q=%22Mabel%27s%20got%20a%20new%20dress%22&f=false)," where a character named Mabel Waring convinces herself to alter an old-fashioned yellow dress and wear it to a fancy party at Mrs. Dalloway's house. Feeling more and more like a fly trapped and liable to drown in a saucer of milk, she intercepts a well-tailored acquaintance, trying to put herself at ease:

> "It's so old-fashioned," she said to Charles Burt, making him stop (which by itself he hated) on his way to talk to someone else.
>
> She meant, or she tried to make herself think that she meant, that it was the picture [on the wall] and not her dress, that was old-fashioned. And one word of praise, one word of affection from Charles would have made all the difference for her at that moment. If he had only said, "Mabel, you're looking charming tonight!" it would have changed her life. But then she ought to have been truthful and direct. Charles said nothing of the kind, of course. He was malice itself. He saw through one, especially if one were feeling particularly mean, paltry, or feeble-minded.
>
> "Mabel's got a new dress!" he said, and the poor fly was absolutely shoved into the middle of the saucer [of milk].

---

In a comment above, NVZ cites an entry for "[nice shoes](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Nice%20Shoes)" at Urban Dictionary indicating that the phrase may be used as pick-up line—a sexual come-on. But Urban Dictionary also has the [following entry](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=resplect), which uses "nice shoes" as a straightforward compliment without ulterior meaning:

> **resplect.** When you reflect the respect. [Example 1:] "Hey man you're wearing a nice tie today" "No dude, I like your tie." Tie resplect [Example 2:] "**Nice shoes**" "No you got nice shoes" Shoes resplect

In short, the guard may have intended "Nice shoes" as a simple compliment, or he may have said it to discomfit you because you were not dressed like most of the other conference attendees. It is highly unlikely that he was trying to proposition you.

Comment: Thank you for the deep insight. That was what I've been looking for. In bavaria we have similarly working ambiguous phrases like _"Guad schaugst aus ..."_

Comment: That's a really awesome answer.

Answer (score 2):

This complement was likely genuine but likely also meant as a humorous, slightly sarcastic understatement.

It's a stereotype almost to the point of cliche in business that you can tell who really has money by looking not at their suit, but at their shoes. The same mentality is also behind the term "well-heeled" meaning wealthy; shoes typically have a pretty hard life as clothing, and it's very tempting to cut corners and wear a more durable or simply a cheaper pair. Expensive shoes in good condition are a mark of someone with enough money to keep them that way and enough attention to detail to care, while someone more practically minded or less attentive might try to get away with a more durable or cheaper and less dressy shoe. The complement, in this context, carries the hidden meaning of "I have noticed that you are well-put-together, head to foot, and I know what that means".

However, as you noticed, you've been showing up significantly overdressed relative to the others in the room. That's because the Internet Age has ushered in a new well-to-do, in the vein of "I'm wealthy, important or otherwise valuable enough that I don't have to impress you with my clothes". In this context the compliment is meant as a humorous understatement more than anything else: "you are so well-dressed compared to your peers that I'm going to single out the least important element of your ensemble to complement". The doorman could just as easily have said, "nice pocket square" if you happened to be sporting one.